# reverse of getParseData: from parsed code back to code

Tags: r, parsing

HI I'm using `getParseData` to fix something in the code. For example replace `=` with `<-`

```
txt = "
flag = F

if(flag){
        dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
} else {
        dat <- 1
}
"

sf = parse(text = txt)
p = getParseData(sf)

p[p$token == 'EQ_ASSIGN', 'text'] = '<-'
```

Now how to go back from `p` - a data.frame showing the parsed code - to R code as a string? Thanks

---

update: try `getParseText`

firstly I can't get the example in `getParseText` to work:

```
fn <- function(x) {
        x + 1 # A comment, kept as part of the source
}

d <- getParseData(fn)
d
# NULL
```

Then I try to mimic the code in `?getParseText` in my example:

```
txt = "
flag = F

f2 = 1 + 1

if(flag){
        dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
} else {
        dat <- 1
}
"

sf = parse(text = txt)
p = getParseData(sf)

plus <- which(p$token == "'+'")
sum <- p$parent[plus]
p[as.character(sum), ]
cat(getParseText(p, sum))
# 1 + 1

cat(getParseText(p, unique(p$parent)))
# not correct

cat(paste0(unique(getParseText(p, p$id)), collapse=" ")) # incorrect
# flag = F f2 1 + 1 1 + if(flag){
#         dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
# } else {
#         dat <- 1
# } if ( ) {
#         dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
# } { dat data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F) data.frame x , stringAsFactor } else {
#         dat <- 1
# } dat <- 1 <-
```

Comment: `?getParseText`

Comment: thank you @Abdou. I couldn't get it work. Pls see update in OP. Would you please give an example? Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `cat(paste0(unique(getParseText(p, p$id)), collapse=" "))` gets the source back, but it seems impossible to run `parse(text=paste0(unique(getParseText(p, p$id)), collapse=" "))`.

Comment: thank you @Abdou  that doesn't seem to work either. Pls see the output I added in OP. Let me know if you heppen to know how to fix it. I'm very confused about the content in the parsed data.frame. thank you-

Comment: This is the best I could have come up with and it's still not as clean: `p[nchar(p$text)==0, 'text'] <- " "; cat(gsub('\\s{2,}', '\n', paste0(p$text, collapse = "")))`.

Comment: thank you@Abdou. The `p` data.frame has line number and column number of each component. I can always write a loop to concatenate them.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `getParseData` to replace the `=` symbols with `<-` in R code.  One of the amazing things about R is that you can operate directly on the language so we will do that here.

```
sf = parse(text = txt)
```

`sf` is an expression object, which effectively is a list of R language objects, one for each top-level statement:

```
sf[[1]]
## flag = F
sf[[2]]
## if (flag) {
##     dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
## } else {
##     dat <- 1
## }
```

The above are language calls.  A call is a an unevaluated R statement, which you get from `parse`, or with `quote`:

```
my.call <- quote(1 + 1)
my.call
## 1 + 1
class(my.call)
## [1] "call"
```

The thing about calls is that R lies to you about their underlying structures.  R calls are lists (well, pairlists really but the distinction is irrelevant here) that R displays and treats specially.  We can show their true nature:

```
as.list(my.call)
## [[1]]
## `+`
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1
```

Note how the leading element of the call is the "function", or in this case the "operator", which in R is just a function anyway (more precisely the name of the function/operator).  This is always the case with calls.  The first element is the function, the following elements are arguments.  R pretends operators are special and displays them differently, but for underlying call structure and evaluation they are the same.

Look at what we can do:

```
my.call[[1]] <- as.name('-')
my.call
## 1 - 1
```

We used `as.name` to create a special type of R object called a symbol.  These can be used to reference functions in calls.  As you can imagine, if we can replace `+` with `-`, we can also do the same for `=` and `<-`.  But to do it systematically we need to recurse through the language tree.  We will write a simple function that does just that:

```
symb_rep <- function(lang, from, to) {
  if(is.call(lang)) {
    if(lang[[1]] == from) lang[[1]] <- to
    lang[-1] <- lapply(lang[-1], symb_rep, from, to)
  }
  lang
}
```

Then we can run it on our original expression, which recall is a list of calls, so we use `lapply` to apply to each element:

```
lang.sub <- lapply(sf, symb_rep, as.name("="), as.name("<-"))
lang.sub
## [[1]]
## flag <- F
## 
## [[2]]
## if (flag) {
##     dat <- data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
## } else {
##     dat <- 1
## }
```

If you want the character representation back you can use `deparse`:

```
unlist(lapply(lang.sub, deparse))
## [1] "flag <- F"                                       
## [2] "if (flag) {"                                     
## [3] "    dat <- data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)"
## [4] "} else {"                                        
## [5] "    dat <- 1"                                    
## [6] "}"
```

Pretty cool, no?

One last point, you'll notice that in `data.frame(x = 1, ...)`, the `=` was not replaced.  Why is that?  Well, that `=` does not actually exist in the call data.  It is displayed by R as decoration.  In reality, notice how the parameter names are stored:

```
as.list(quote(data.frame(x=1, y=2)))
## [[1]]
## data.frame
## 
## $x
## [1] 1
## 
## $y
## [1] 2
```

There is no `=` in sight, because the parameter names are just names of the call object.  R just displays equal signs as a visual aid when it prints out the call, and interprets them the same way when it parses the call.  This "lie" is why these two expressions are semantically distinct:

```
data.frame(x <- 5)
##   x....5
## 1      5
x
## [1] 5
data.frame(x = 1)
##   x
## 1 1
x
## [1] 5
```

In the former R assigns 5 to x in the global environment, and makes up a name for the data frame parameter.  In the second R uses `x` as the parameter name but doesn't assign to the global environment.  Because R relies on the `=` in parameter lists to get parameter names it cannot use it with the normal assignment semantics.

Comment: Very nice answer that well summarizes the core concept of how to operate on R itself! Just one question though: shouldn't it be `symb_rep` instead if `symb_rep_fun`? You just want to call the function that you're defining recursively, right?

Comment: @Rappster absolutely correct, I had both defined in my session.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different use case that actually required more manipulation of parsed data and I stumbled across this question. In case anyone else needs a way to "revert" the output of `getParseData()`.

Note: trailing white spaces or lines only consisting of white spaces cannot be recovered from the result of `getParseData()` because white spaces are ignored from parsing.

#### Input

```
txt = "
flag = F
      
if(flag){
        dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
} else {
        dat <- 1
}
"
```

#### Solution

```
parse_data <- getParseData(parse(text = txt))

# exclude empty tokens
parse_data <- parse_data[nzchar(parse_data$text), ]

# NOT recoverable: lines ending with white spaces
res <- by(data = parse_data,
          # consider each line separately
          INDICES = list(parse_data$line1), 
          FUN = function(args) {
            # determine number of tokens in the line
            n_tokens <- length(args$text)
            
            # determine width of white space needed prior to each token
            # it is its starting position minus 
            # the end position of the precessing token minus 1 
            # since positions are including
            n_ws <- args$col1 - c(0, args$col2[-n_tokens]) - 1
            
            # create needed whitespace
            ws <- strrep(" ", n_ws)
            
            # add whitespaces to the tokens
            paste(ws, args$text, collapse = "", sep = "")
          })

# recover empty lines
out <- character(max(parse_data$line1))
out[unique(parse_data$line1)] <- res
```

#### Result

```
cat(paste(out, collapse = "\n"))
#> 
#> flag = F
#> 
#> if(flag){
#>         dat = data.frame(x = 1, stringAsFactor = F)
#> } else {
#>         dat <- 1
#> }
```